# How to retrieve variable values outside ajax call?

Tags: ajax, variables

I have an ajax function call that has a variable sum with value as 5. But when I try to access this variable outside the ajax function call, am getting null value.
Is there any way to access the value outside the ajax function?

```
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "Service.asmx/chart",
           data: appid,
           success: function(data) {
           var mydata = 5;    
                }
            });
           alert(mydata);
```

Comment: sorry, here consider the variable mydata. Im not able to retrieve the value of it outside ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Service.asmx/chart",
       data: appid,
       success: function(data) {
       doGetMyData(data);
            }
        });
       function doGetMyData(data){
       alert(data);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The first "A" in AJAX means Asynchronous, so your code runs the alert before the request completes. To achieve the goals you want, you may try to make your request synchronous adding the async:false option to your query:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Service.asmx/chart",
   data: appid,
   async:false,
   success: function(data) {
   doGetMyData(data);
        }
    });
   function doGetMyData(data){
      alert(data);
   }
```

The bad news is synchronous request locks your browser until it's finish, it's a good pratice to avoid this.